# Dropdown menu hidden in Drupal 8 not working

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, drupal-8

im trying to create a dropdown menu that shows when a user clicks on it, and closes whether the user clicks on it again or clicks outside of the menu. Now I have a working script thanks to this community : http://jsfiddle.net/aL7Xe/1000/

But when using this on my drupal 8 site it does not work, any ideas ?

jQuery im using :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.topmenu').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('hide'); 
    });
  $('html').on('click', function(){
        $('.dropdown-menu').addClass('hide');   
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

SOLVED :

I solved it already, turns out when I was looking at the debugging function in firefox @ the console it said error $ is not a function. I then added $ at the first line so it became like this `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` 
And the error was gone and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blomkfist174,

I am glad you got your JQuery working.  I thought I would offer this code for you to use in the future.  See the comments for when the code will load/execute:

```
(function (Drupal, $, window) {

  // To understand behaviors, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2269515
  Drupal.behaviors.themename = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      // Execute code once the DOM is ready. $(document).ready() not required within Drupal.behaviors.

      //Code in your example would go here:
      //----------------------------------------------
      $('.topmenu').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('hide'); 
      });
      $('html').on('click', function(){
        $('.dropdown-menu').addClass('hide');   
      });
      //----------------------------------------------


      $(window).load(function () {
        // Execute code once the window is fully loaded.


      });

      $(window).scroll(function () {
        // Execute code when the window scrolls.


      });
    }
  };
} (Drupal, jQuery, this));
```

Coding your Theme's JS in this way will allow you to interact with other Drupal libraries.  For example, you can run JS after Ajax has run.  You will need to modify the code below to match your theme name on this line:

```
Drupal.behaviors.themename = {
```

I created my theme from the Basic theme.  This JS file was provided as a starting point.  I also use gulp to take my Source JS files and uglify/minify them.  Taking that approach allows me to have a source file with nice formatting and comments, but a min file that is used on the site.

I hope this helps!